# How to get the ref path to a specified remote branch in Git

Tags: git

I'd like to get the path to the file of a specified remote ref.

> Although in some cases the file name is obvious like in 
>   `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master`, it isn't obvious in other cases
>   like `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` where HEAD points to master.

I'm writing a tool which requires touching each remote file, but it fails in the second case from above.

In order to solve that problem, I thought in these two possibilities:

**1-** Run a git command to return the ref file name of a specific remote branch. Something equivalent to:

```
$ git ---give-me-the-ref-of origin/master
refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

**2-** Run a git command to guarantee that the tracked remote branch have a ref file (despite HEAD). Something equivalent to:

```
$ git checkout --track ---use-explicit-ref-besides-HEAD master
```

> Do you know how to achieve any of the 2 options above?

Comment: I don't understand why you want the name of a *file* in `.git/refs` that contains the ID of the upstream of a branch, but there's a big potential pitfall: there may not *be* a separate file, if the reference has been "packed".  A packed reference is one of many found in `.git/packed-refs`.  Refs generally get packed during the automatic gc, and are split out into individual files on subsequent changes to them (then repacked later by a later gc).  (`git gc` runs `git pack-refs`, which users can also run, so there are more ways to get this state.)

Comment: My approach was wrong because I was stubborn with using remote references by name.
What I did instead was to use `git rev-parse origin/master` to get the hash, which worked for what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was wrong because it was assuming that all refs to remotes existed as single files, but as [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) mentioned a subset of the refs can be listed in .git/packed-refs as well.

What I did instead was to use `git rev-parse origin/master` to get the remote branch hash and I used that instead.